# Перенести приложение на другой рабочий стол

Tags: linux, ubuntu, интерфейс

Как через консоль `UBUNTU` перенести приложение на другой рабочий стол
уже открытое приложение, например `nautilus`
или открыть его на нужном рабочем столе например под номером `4`

Comment: скорей всего копать в сторону `wmctrl` надо...

Comment: wmctrl полезная программа спасибо

Comment: а если только сочетания клавиш знаете, то `xdotool`

Comment: думаю речь об Ubuntu 16.0 или 17 в которой по умолчанию Gnome http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/gnome-shell-make-applications-start-on.html?m=1

Comment: [практически ответ на данный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/943052/178576)

Answer (score -1):

Ну смотри, заходишь в это приложение и нажимаешь: ctrl + alt + shift + стрелка в ту сторону, где у тебя находится нужный рабочий стол. У меня все заработало. Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: замечательный ответ, только не на тот вопрос, который был задан.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).