# Как сделать лаунчер, запускающий программу на определённом рабочем столе?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Хотелось бы, чтоб всякие фоновые приложения, вроде серверов, запускались на отдельно отведённом для них рабочем месте. Можно ли так сделать?

Comment: 1. непонятно, что именно подразумевается под термином «определённый рабочий стол». 2. и какое вообще отношение серверы могут к этому иметь иметь.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin 1) https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-workspaces.html.ru определённый - тот, который можно было бы определить в лаунчере или скрипте, запускаемом лаунчером. 2) прямого отношения не имеют, я просто привёл пример. смысл рабочих столов в том, чтобы разбить открытые окна по группам и отдельно между ними переключаться. в моём случае клиентские/повседневные приложения (как правило гуишные) - первая группа, серверные/фоновые (терминалы) - вторая.

Comment: теперь понятнее для окружающих, но сложнее для вас: это про какой-то частный случай реализации wm-а. вопрос очень узкоспецифичный. смотрите документацию именно к конкретному используемому вами wm-у.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, на самом деле на концепцию виртуальных рабочих столов и интерфейс к wm'у есть [спецификация](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/wm-spec/), так что это не частный случай.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, кто же спорит? термин «workspace», конечно, существует: в [упомянутой вами документации](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html) он даже четыре раза упоминается. вот только про интерфейс взаимодействия там ни слова. т.е. возвращаемся «к нашим баранам»: «это частный случай, см. документацию к конкретному wm-у«. правильно? // вообще термин весьма многозначный, и в первом комментарии я и просил раскрыть подразумеваемое значение.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, «workspace» — это новое модное словечко для обозначения старого доброго «virtual desktop», или просто «desktop», как в спеце про него говорят... интерфейс управления положением окон на рабочих столах вполне описан — посылка перечисленных сообщений через icccm. Всё это поддерживается [почти] всеми WM созданными за последние лет 15 (конечно исключая безвестные наколенные поделки).

Comment: @Fat-Zer, «virtual desktop» (что, как вы утверждаете, эквивалентно тому, что подразумевает автор вопроса, в чём я не уверен), относится к [**no**-icccm features](https://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/latest/ar01s02.html#idm139870834774432), т.е., «implementation specific». вернулись «к нашим баранам». // p.s. предлагаю завязывать с «поиском серебрянной пули». всё равно её не существует.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, «no-icccm feature» — это всё, что описано конкретно в данной спецификацией, а не собственно icccm... да эти фичи не обязательные, но если они имплементируется конкретным WM'ом, то они обычно соответствуют данной спецификации... Очевидно, что большинство wm «для всех» поддерживают управление рабочими столами. Единственное что API скорей всего не достаточно удобный для того, чтобы нормально сделать то, что хочет OP, так что придётся извращаться с хаками из серии «ждать пока приложение создаст окно, а потом перемещать его на нужный рабочий стол».

Comment: @Fat-Zer, последний раз (дальше поддерживать дискуссию не вижу смысла): управление местоположением окна в той или иной реализации workspace/virtual_desktop/и_т.п. — не описано никакими стандартами, зависит от реализации конкретного wm, по поводу чего надо обратиться в первую очередь к документации этого wm. это всё, что я хотел донести до автора вопроса.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, /согласен про последний раз/ это описано в приведённой спецификации от freedesktop, которой следует большинство wm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Управление положением окон на рабочих столах в большинстве WM реализовано согласно [этой](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/wm-spec/) freesesktop'овыской спецификации. На основе оной спеки существует консольная утилитка [`wmctrl`](http://sweb.cz/tripie/utils/wmctrl). API самой спецификации не содержит чего-либо похожего на «запустить X на рабочем столе N», так что я вижу два варианта:

1. Переключиться на рабочий стол N<sup>1</sup> и запустить приложение:

   ```
   wmctrl -s 1 && xterm
   ```
2. Запомнить список окон → запустить приложение → когда появится новое окно перенести его на рабочий стол N; это потребует небольшого скрипта и не совсем надёжно, если приложение создаёт несколько окон или окно приветствия.
   ***⚠** Осторожно, дальше разбросаны граблевидные костыли.*

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   [[ "$#" -lt 2 ]] && {
       echo "Usage: $0 <desktop> <command> [arg] ..."
       exit 1
   }

   getWinIdList(){
       wmctrl -l | sed 's/\s.*//'
   }

   DESKTOP=$1
   shift

   WL="$(getWinIdList)"

   #run the process
   "$@" &

   # Loop up to 20 seconds and wait for new window apperence
   i=0
   while [[ "$((i++))" -lt 200 ]]; do
       newWL="$(getWinIdList)"
       # check if there are new windows
       wins=$(diff <(echo -n "$WL") <(echo -n "$newWL") | sed -n '/^>/p')
      [[ -n "$wins" ]]  && break

      sleep 0.1 || break
   done

   # if new windows were detected, move them.
   if [[ -n "$wins" ]]; then
       for w in $wins; do
           wmctrl -ir "$w" -t "$DESKTOP"
       done
   else
       echo "The timeout expired no new windows detected."
   fi
   ```

   Запуск:

   ```
   runOnDesktop.sh 1 xterm
   ```

---

Вообще говоря, я не думаю, что существует способ (DE/WM/платформо-зависимый или нет) как-либо надёжно заставить произвольное приложение запускать все свои окна на каком-либо столе исходя просто из того факта, как утроено взаимодействие процессов, оконного менеджера и X11.

---

<sup>¹ Рабочие столы отсчитываются с нулевого</sup>

Comment: Очень костыльное решение, особенно учитывая эту задержку, ждущую запуска приложения. На практике я бы им пользоваться точно не стал, но понятно, что лучше здесь вряд ли можно что-то придумать. Спасибо!

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf, гипотетически, задержку можно заменить на [ожидание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/925290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-x11-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bc) появления новых окон, но готовой утилиты я для этого не видел.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы зайдете по ssh и запустите

```
DISPLAY=:0 /home/user/app.sh
```

то приложение откроется на мониторе, если таковой имеется,

мне кажется по аналогии можно решить и ваш вопрос